# Swift Dynamic json Values Reading and Writing

Tags: json, swift, struct, encoding, decoding

**Problem Stuck On**

I am trying to be able to read out my json file data to the console log for testing so I can use it later on.

Im not sure how to finish off my other structs due to varying data size and possible bad json format.

Once I finish that I believe I would need to use a for loop for read the varying size of data from "M", "S" and "WP" (This part shouldn't be complicated I believe)

**Possible Things to Consider**

I want to write and add data to "M" "S" "WP"

The data amount for ("M", "S") could be any number of String Array data objects

The data in "WP" Might need a different format I would like to add a name("abc") with a Int array containing any number of data points

**Note: My Json Format Might Be Wrong in Some Areas concerning MP and WP**

Swift Code To Grab Data

```
import Foundation


struct UserDay: Codable {
    let mp: UserMP
    let wp: UserWP
}

struct UserMP: Codable {
    let m: [UserM]
    let s: [UserS]
}

struct UserM : Codable {
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let time: String
}
struct UserS : Codable {
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let time: String
}


struct UserWP: Codable {
    let wp: [WPData]
}

struct WPData: Codable {
    let title: String
    let values: [Int]
}


class LogDataHandler {
    
    
    public func grabJSONInfo(){
        guard let jsonURL = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "LogData", ofType: "json") else { return }
        
        guard let jsonString = try? String(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: jsonURL), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else { return }
        
        // Print Info for TESTING
        var year: UserDay?
        
        do {
            year = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserDay.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
        } catch {
            print("ERROR WHEN DECODING JSON")
        }
        
        guard let results = year else {
            print("YEAR IS NIL")
            return
        }
        
        print(results)
        
    }
    
    
}
```

JSON Example Data Below

```
{
    "01/01/2020": {
   
        "MP" : {
            "M" : [
                {"title" : "m1", "description" : "1", "time" : "12:30pm"},
                {"title" : "m2", "description" : "2", "time" : "1:30pm"},
                {"title" : "m3", "description" : "3", "time" : "2:30pm"}
            ],
            "S" : [
                {"title" : "s1", "description" : "1", "time" : "1pm"}
            ]
        },
        "WP" : [
            { "title" : "abc", "values" :  [12, 10, 6]},
            { "title" : "def", "values" :  [8]}
        ]
    },
    "01/29/2020": {
        
        "MP" : {
            "M" : [{"title" : "m1", "description" : "1", "time" : "12:30pm"}],
            "S" : [{"title" : "s1", "description" : "1", "time" : "12:30pm"}]
        },
        "WP" :[{ "title" : "def", "values" :  [8]}]
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You can just make optionals the properties that sometimes are missing. For example, in `UserWP`, you'd have: `var abc, def: [Int]?`. However, `M` and `S` are not a valid JSON with `{ [...],[...] }`, so you'd need to fix that if you want to decode it with `JSONDecoder`

Comment: @NewDev I updated my json and code but my output is ERROR WHEN DECODING JSON and YEAR IS NIL

Comment: also this error when i printed localized error  `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`

Comment: Your JSON is still malformed - use any online JSON validators sites to fix it (ex: [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)). The other challenge you'll have is with `monthX` properties. This would require manual decoding. Also, what's the meaning of `"1"`s? Is this always `"1"`?

Comment: @NewDev thats 1 is just a day number is it just showing day 1 not day 1-30

Comment: I see. Keep in mind that your current models don't actually store the year (e.g. the value `"2020"`) or the day - not sure if this is intentional or not. And fix your JSON to specify what's the root object you want to decode - is it an object that holds an array of years? Is it a dictionary of `[String: UserYear]`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216792/discussion-between-justadummy-and-new-dev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and our chat, this seems to be a question of the right way to construct the Swift models and the JSON object.

Based on your (updated) JSON, you might want to decode your data into a `[String: UserDay]` - a dictionary with a date string as key and `UserDay` as a value.

**First**, `WP` property in your JSON is just an array of objects (that map to `WPData`), so it's best to change your `UserDay.wp` to be `[WPData]` instead of `UserWP`:

```
struct UserDay: Codable {
    let mp: UserMP
    let wp: [WPData] // <-- changed
}
```

**Second**, some of your models' properties don't match directly to what's in JSON because keys-properties mapping is case sensitive. You can explicitly define `CodingKeys` to map them:

```
struct UserDay: Codable {
    let mp: UserMP
    let wp: [WPData]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case mp = "MP", wp = "WP"
    }
}

struct UserMP: Codable {
    let m: [UserM]
    let s: [UserS]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case m = "M", s = "S"
    }
}
```

Now you're ready to decode `[String: UserDay]`:

```
let userDays = try JSONDecoder().decoder([String: UserDay].self, from: jsonData)

let userDay = userDays["01/29/2020"]
```

---

Of course, working with `String` instead of `Date` isn't very convenient. Unfortunately, `Dictionary`'s conformance to `Codable` only supports `Int` or `String` as keys (AFAIK).

So, let's do a manual decoding into a new root object `UserData` that works with `Date`s:

```
struct UserData: Codable {
   var userDays: [Date: UserDay]

   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
       let dict = try container.decode([String: UserDay].self)

       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
       dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

       // decode (String, UserDay) pairs into an array of (Date, UserDay)
       let pairs = dict.compactMap { (key, value) -> (Date, UserDay)? in
           guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: key) else { return nil }
           return (date, value)
       }

       // uniquing is used just in case there non unique keys
       self.userDays = Dictionary(pairs, uniquingKeysWith: {(first, _) in first})
   }
}
```

Now, we can decode into this `UserData` object:

```
let userData = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserData.self, from: jsonData)

let todaysData = userData.userDays[Date()]
```

Comment: how do you use userDays userDay userData todaysData? Or where do you use them, When I tried I got this error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data'"

Comment: I replaced your jsonData  in the decoding with jsonString, so its coming from json string

Comment: oh.. no, it needs to be something like `if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) { /* decode here */ }`